# Trying to sort a stack in descending order using a queue

Tags: stack, queue

I was thinking of using a temp variable to hold values popped off the stack, adding them to the queue, and then removing values from the queue, and pushing them onto the stack until it is sorted, but this isn't really working out. Also, no other data structures are allowed other than the stack and queue operations.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Use this pseudo code to sort stack ask if any confusion

```
sort(Stack S)
{
    if (S is not empty)
    {
        // Pop the top element off the stack
        int t = S.pop();
        //Sort the remaining stack recursively
        Sort(s)
        //Push the top element back into the sorted stack 
        insert(S, t)
    }
}

insert(Stack S, int t) {
    if (S.isEmpty())
        S.push(t);
    else if (t > S.top())
        // t is at its position in sorted stack
        S.push(t);
    else {
        int u = S.pop();
        insert(S, t);
        S.push(u);
    }
}
```